# java How to access textField after added to ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a button that gets an number from a text field then creates that number of textFields. It adds the text Fields to an ArrayList. I then create another button. This button needs to get the new value for each test field and add it to an ArrayList. How can I access the new values in each text field. Any help is appreciated. My code is bellow.

```
public class BallonBustSetupFrame {
    static int numberOfBallons;
    JFrame setup;
    JLayeredPane lp;
    int setBoundsX = 120;
    int setBoundsY = 220;
    ArrayList<String> prizeList = new ArrayList();
    String prizeString;
    JTextField prizeTextBox;


    public BallonBustSetupFrame (){
        setup = new JFrame("Setup");
        lp = new JLayeredPane();
        setup.getContentPane().add(lp);

        setup.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ImageIcon splashPic = new ImageIcon("splash3.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(splashPic);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBounds(0,0,600,600);

        JLabel numberOfBallonsLabel = new JLabel("Number of Ballons:");
        numberOfBallonsLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        numberOfBallonsLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        numberOfBallonsLabel.setBounds(120, 150, 140, 50);

        JTextField numberOfBallonsTextBox = new JTextField(50);
        numberOfBallonsTextBox.setBounds(260, 160, 50, 30);
        numberOfBallonsTextBox.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        numberOfBallonsTextBox.setText("10");

        JLabel numberOfBallonsNoteLable = new JLabel("(Number of Ballons must be between 2 and 15)");
        numberOfBallonsNoteLable.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 10));
        numberOfBallonsNoteLable.setForeground(Color.white);
        numberOfBallonsNoteLable.setBounds(120, 180, 250, 50);

        JButton okButton = new JButton("Quit");
        okButton.setBounds(400,550,95, 0x1e);
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JButton startGameButton = new JButton("Start");
        startGameButton.setBounds(120,550,95, 0x1e);
        startGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                //Need to access the textFields values


//                BallonBustFrame startGame = new BallonBustFrame();
//                closeFrame();
            }
        });

        JButton numberOfBallonsButton = new JButton("Set");
        numberOfBallonsButton.setBounds(360,160,95, 0x1e);
        numberOfBallonsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                numberOfBallons = Integer.parseInt(numberOfBallonsTextBox.getText());
                System.out.println(numberOfBallons);
                lp.remove(numberOfBallonsButton);
                //creates the textFields
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBallons; i++ ){
                    createPrizePanels();
                    setBoundsX = setBoundsX +125;
                    if(setBoundsX > 450){
                        setBoundsX = 120;
                        setBoundsY = setBoundsY + 65;
                    }
                }
                lp.add(startGameButton);
            }
        });

        lp.add(okButton);
        lp.add(numberOfBallonsButton);
        lp.add(numberOfBallonsLabel);
        lp.add(numberOfBallonsTextBox);
        lp.add(numberOfBallonsNoteLable);
        lp.add(label);
        setup.setSize(620, 650);
        setup.setVisible(true);
    }   

    public int getNumberOfBallons() {
        return numberOfBallons;
    }

    public void createPrizePanels(){
        JLabel prizePanel = new JLabel("Enter Prize Here", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        prizePanel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        prizePanel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        prizePanel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1);
        prizePanel.setBorder(border);
        prizePanel.setOpaque(true);
        prizePanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        prizePanel.setBounds(setBoundsX, setBoundsY, 120, 60);

        prizeTextBox = new JTextField(50);
        prizeTextBox.setBounds(setBoundsX + 5, setBoundsY + 20, 110, 30);
        prizeTextBox.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        prizeTextBox.setOpaque(true);
        prizeTextBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        prizeTextBox.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        prizeTextBox.setText("No Prize");
        prizeTextBox.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        lp.add(prizePanel);
        lp.add(prizeTextBox); 

    }

    public void closeFrame(){
        setup.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: No huge mystery here: let's say you have your field list as `ArrayList<JTextField> textFieldList` and the index of the field you want to access is `i`, just use  `textFieldList.get(i).getText()`.  But be sure you've defined `textFieldList` as a class member variable, and **not** as a local variable inside some method.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Thanks for the reply. The text in each textField is set to no prize. The user will enter new text. My code isn't getting the new text. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the code you're showing the most recent?  I don't see any `JTextField`s getting added to any `ArrayList`s anywhere?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson. I realised I had a logic error. I was creating two sets of JTextFields and adding and accessing the wrong ones. The code below has fixed my problem. Thanks very much for your time. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to get all components to identify which is of type `JTextField` and iterate:

```
Arrays.asList(lp.getComponents()).forEach(component -> {
   if (component instanceof JTextField) {
      // System.out.println(((JTextField) component).getText());
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you mate. That did the trick. Although I'm getting an warning for the top line forEach(component -> {

Comment: what's the warning? can you share